# Is fopen_s easy to refactor into CreateFile

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

A program creates a file on a windows machine to log its progress. At the end of the program the file is closed and remains on the system. Users with network access want to open the file remotely to see the recently logged entries.

The file is opened using `fopen_s` there is no mentioning of shared mode in the documentation. Using Ansi-C90 is a requirement.

The used call looks like this:

```
e += fopen_s(&(logger->logData.fileHandle), fp.Path, "a");
```

Is CreateFile an option for me? I read that it is not Ansi-C90.
Is `fopen_s` easy to refactor into `CreateFile` without breaking any other code?
Against what sort of possible refactor problems should i write unittests?
Are there other ways to open the file in sharedmode that i am missing?

Comment: "Files opened by fopen_s and _wfopen_s are not sharable. If you require that a file be sharable, use _fsopen, _wfsopen with the appropriate sharing mode constant (for example, _SH_DENYNO for read/write sharing)."

Comment: @loreb can you make your comment into an answer so i can accept it? thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Files opened by fopen_s and _wfopen_s are not sharable. If you require that a file be sharable, use _fsopen, _wfsopen with the appropriate sharing mode constant (for example, _SH_DENYNO for read/write sharing)."

(comment turned into answer per Johannes' request)